# How to evaluate the mathematical expression in Java?

Tags: java, math, expression

I need to write a Java program to solve similar mathematical expressions like below. I am using ScriptEngineManager, but ScriptEngineManager is not a requirement; it could be any anything to solve my problem.

Let's take an example: `exp = 100*(2**4)` so answer should be 1600 but I am getting 204.

Consider `**` as the *power* operator for example: `(2**4 =>Math.pow(2,4));`

Replacing `**` with `^` is simply not working (getting wrong answer as shown above), without power operator (`**`) everything is working fine, consider this example: `(6*(4/2)+3*1)` = answer 15 as expected. so I just need to handle `**`.

Flow of Program:

1. User take an input using input scanner.
2. Get calculated value from input expression.

Comment: `100*java.util.Math.pow(2, 4)` as there is no `**` operator, and `^` is the bitwise XOR operator. One could do here `100*(1<<4)` using the bit-shift-left operator.

Comment: #Joop Eggen Yes I know, `^` has different meaning like you said.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate power in java, please use `Math.pow` method:

```
var exp = 100 * Math.pow(2, 4);
```

There is no `**` operator in java.

Comment: #Andronicus This is not my expression structure as I wrote I must need to handle `double asterisk` during program execution.